# Complex measures that are the same on the open sets

Tags: measure-theory

So if i have two complex measures that agree on the open sets they are going to be the same on the borel $\sigma$-algebra. I have no idea how to prove this, i know this isnt true for positive measures.Any tips or advice is aprecciated.

Comment: This is true for positive measures which are finite (the finiteness assumption can be relaxed given another condition). The standard proof uses [Dynkin classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system). I believe you should be able to use this for your problem as well. See also [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#Example).

Comment: There is a simple proof using directly the fact that the measures are finite and the definition of $\sigma$-algebra. I posted it as an answer. Please let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be two complex measures defined in a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ and suppose that all the open sets are in $\Sigma$.

Define 
$$ \Sigma_1 = \{A\in \Sigma : \mu_1(A) = \mu_2(A) \} $$

Since $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are complex measures, they are finite measures, and so we can prove (directly from the definition of $\sigma$-algebra) that $\Sigma_1 $ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Since $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ agree on the open sets, we have that all open sets are in $\Sigma_1 $, so the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is contained in $\Sigma_1 $. That means: $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the same on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.